# What is the $create function in ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm familiar with `$get()` and `$find()`. But, I've just stumbled across some code I need to work on that calls a function `$create()`. I can't find anything online or in the code explaining it. The slightly modified call is here:

```
$create(namespace.aspnetclass, {id: 'foo', groupId: <%= groupId %>}, 
    null, null, $get('divContainer'));
```

What is `$create()` *supposed* to do? Right now, it is doing nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`$create`](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Global/CreateShortcutMethod.aspx) is a shortcut for the [`Sys.Component.create()`](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys/ComponentClass/ComponentCreateMethod.aspx) method that is part of the MS Ajax Library and is used to create components (often referred to as *controls* and *behaviours*)

```
$create(type, properties, events, references, element);
```

Comment: As a side note - I'd recommend ASP.NET AJAX in Action as a good reference on the library. New edition in the works as we speak - http://manning.com/gallo2/